# How do I hold a request on the k8s until pods is ready?

Tags: kubernetes

On k8s, when I requests to pods and all pods are in use (not ready), the requests will be timeout immediately.
I want to hold the request until a pod is ready and then the request is sent to the pod.

Do you know a sort of timeout duration settings for load balancing?
Also, I couldn't find any relevant documentation on this matter, am I fundamentally misunderstanding something?

PS:
I use Readiness probe. The case I say is that Readiness probes of all pod return false, so all pods are in use.

Answer (score 4):

Please try to use Readiness/Liveliness probe, This is required for kubernetes.

Based on both status(After success) kubernetes will notify and accordingly kubernetes will redirect the request to respective pod, as pods are ready and live, now they will be able to process the request.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But, I already used Readiness probe. The case I say is all pods' readiness probes are false (all pods are in use (not ready)).  In the situation, a request is timeout.
I want to hold the request until a pod's readiness probe is true.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute [`kubectl wait`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#wait) command:

```
$ kubectl wait ([-f FILENAME] | resource.group/resource.name | resource.group [(-l label | --all)]) [--for=delete|--for condition=available]
```

```
$ kubectl wait pod-running <pod-name>
$ kubectl wait pod-running @pod-id
$ kubectl create -c example.json | kubectl wait pod-running -  # accept from pod name/ID from stdin
$ kubectl wait pod-template <pod-name> --format-template='{{ if .Status.Condition == "Running" }}1{{ else }}0{{ end }}'
```

You could also define custom in plugins or config files.

Take a look: [kubernetes-conditions-api](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/1899).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like there are two ways that can be followed.

1. Add an init-container to check the dependant pod's health and once ready proceed next.

or

2. Add health checkers for the dependent pod by the setting of readiness probe with your pod manifests.